# PTD software alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, partitioning, data-recovery

What is the alternative for PTD on ubuntu?

The partition table doctor (PTD) does not have a linux version

And what are the compatible partitions that it can handle: NTFS,ext2,3,4,btrfs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GParted. Its a good software that has more capabilities than PTD.

[image: Download for ubuntu]

[image]